# Woocommerce Rest API add custom data to productslist

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm reviewing my custom endpoints for a Woocommerce Rest API. My endpoints are working with the /wp-json/wc/**v1**/products 
Basically I'm adding the vendor ID to the products. Now I need to change my rest api to V3 and I have issues. I get the key "vendor_id". But I could not fix to get the vendor(author) ID of the products.

Firstly I changed my filter from:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_product', array( $this, 'get_vendor_product' ),10,3);
```

to

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_object', array( $this, 'get_vendor_product_new' ),20,3);
```

With this change I could arrange, that the value is in the json response.

my new function looks like that:

```
public function get_vendor_product_new($response, $object, $request) {
if( empty( $response->data ) )  
    return $response;   

    $vendor_id = $object->post_author;
    $response->data['vendor_id'] = $vendor_id;

  return $response; 

}
```

The response is "null"

Could you support to fix this?